# Javascript Array.prototype.sort() wrong without comparing function

Tags: javascript

I found that using sort without comparing function would result in wrong answer and I don't know the reason.

```
var a = [823564440,115438165,784484492,74243042,114807987,137522503,441282327,16531729,823378840,143542612]

a.sort()
a.sort((a,b) => a-b)
```

The two should give same result in my mind, but they don't. And clearly the latter is correct.

```
a.sort()
[114807987, 115438165, 137522503, 143542612, 16531729, 441282327, 74243042, 784484492, 823378840, 823564440]
a.sort((a, b) => a-b)
[16531729, 74243042, 114807987, 115438165, 137522503, 143542612, 441282327, 784484492, 823378840, 823564440]
```

Can anyone tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): *The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.*

Comment: First compares items as if they were strings.

Comment: String sort vs. Numeric sort.

Comment: @AndrewLi Make your comment the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. **The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.** (Emphasis mine)†

Since you do not supply a function, default sort order is used. Thus, the elements are sorted as if they were *strings*, versus the latter sort, where it is sorted based on number value.

Because of this, `1` comes before `2`, `2` before `3` etc. no matter the number of digits as strings are compared place by place. (See [list of unicode characters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters); since 1 in Unicode is U+0031, it comes before U+0032 and is thus smaller).

In your example, this would mean `115438165` coming before `74243042` although the latter is smaller mathematically. Because the strings are compared place by place, `1` is compared to `7` and is less than, thus yielding the result. For further reading, see [lexicographical order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

---

† This is by specification. See the [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-sortcompare), **Section 22.1.3.24.1 - Runtime Semantics: `SortCompare( x, y )`**. Here, it explains that if no sorting function is passed, string representations of `x` and `y` (found using [`ToString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring)) are compared.

Comment: Thanks! It is quite strange for a numerical array to do like this.

Comment: @xgwang It may seem weird that this is done but (I believe) the logical reason is because the array can hold anything - not just numbers. What if no sort function is passed and you have an array of non-numeric objects? Instead of sorting numerically, it sorts based on string representation.

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order.